# Spring data redis template(xml config) using lettuce

Tags: templates, redis, spring-data

We are  using spring 4 for our application(xml config)
And looking to integrate spring data redis with underlying lettuce driver. We would like to use spring redis template for store/retrive objects.
Examples we are gettinv mostly on spring boot which ww dont want as our application not in spring boot

Any good reference implementations really helpful